# JSF + Wildfly conexão em vários bancos dinamicamente

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jpa, conexão, wildfly

Olá, tenho uma aplicação Web utilizando JSF + CDI + JPA e o WildFly 8 como servidor de aplicação. Até o momento estou deixando o servidor gerenciar as transações, onde as informações de conexão com o banco de dados, serviços de email, autenticação... estão nas configurações do servidor (standalone.xml). Agora meu problema é que preciso que o sistema acesse várias bases de dados. De forma que quando o cliente for logar, ele coloque seu login e senha e também escolha a base de dados.

Já pesquisei bastante e soluções como multi-tenancy não pareceram muito interessantes. Pensei também em tirar essa responsabilidade do servidor, fazendo a conexão na aplicação e ainda conseguindo utiliza as injeções normalmente, mas eu teria que fazer muitas alterações no sistema.

Alguma dica ou ideia de como resolver este problema?

Obrigado desde já galera!

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Estou utilizando uma abordagem em que eu crio meus EntityManagers dinamicamente durante a aplicação mesmo. De forma que eu altero apenas o atributo jta-data-source  e assim consigo mudar a base de dados que eu acesso. Funciona, mas estou com 2 problemas:

1. Ao trocar de base de dados o Eclipselink demora bastante, pois ele executa todas aquelas validações de quando iniciamos o servidor.
2. Mesmo com a lentidão, consigo conectar ao banco normalmente e fazer login. O sistema lista dos dados cadastrados corretamente. Porém o problema está na hora de persistir os dados criar/ alterar e excluir. Tenho problemas na transação e a persistência não acontece.

Esse é um exemplo do que estou fazendo para criar os Entity Managers dinamicamente (na minha aplicação só muda na forma de enviar o nome do banco, apenas simplifiquei o código):

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationResources {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces
    @Default
    @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager produceEntityManager() {
        Map<Object, Object> props = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        props.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JTA_DATASOURCE, DATABASENAME);
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU", props);
        return  entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void dispose(@Disposes EntityManager entityManager) {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Depois disso eu removi as anotações @PersistenceContext das minhas classes Stateless e coloquei as anotações @Inject, assim o entityManager passa a ser o que eu criei dinamicamente. Estou definindo meus datasources no standalone.xml do Wildfly e elas são do tipo xa-datasource.

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste link [acessando-multiplos-bancos-de-dados-com-jpa-e-cdi](http://blog.caelum.com.br/acessando-multiplos-bancos-de-dados-com-jpa-e-cdi/) Já utilizei deste guia, funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Eu estou fazendo algo deste tipo agora... mas estou criando os entity managers dinamicamente, alterando apenas o atributo jta-data-source. Não posso fazer segundo o link que me mandou porque ele define às unidades de persistência de forma estática.  No meu caso eu posso ter N clientes e N banco de dados (é um requisito do sistema).  Então o que eu fiz foi alterar o atributo  jta-data-source na hora da criação do entity manager. Mas ainda tenho problemas.

Comment: O problema disso tudo é  que quando eu altero a base de dados jta o eclipse link conecta no outro banco e demora muito. Mas no fim ele como segue conectar. O problema depois disso é  que tive problemas com a persistência de dados. Apenas consigo buscar dados do banco é não mais excluir, alterar ou criar. Vou atualizar a pergunta colocando o código Sá nova abordagem que estou tentando.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema da lentidão em conectar nos outros bancos. Agora tenho o segundo problema, após logar eu não consigo remover nem criar/editar os objetos no banco.

Comment: A solução foi em remover essa pasta no Wildfly (como sugerido nessa [questão](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490328/what-causes-arjuna-1603-could-not-find-new-xaresource-to-use-for-recovering-non) e depois coloquei o atributo do eclipselink validation-only para "true" https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_validation_only.htm. Agora consigo alterar entre os bancos e logar em cada usuário específico de cada banco. O problema continua que eu não consigo salvar nem excluir os objetos  no banco.

Comment: Eu resolvi o problema! Eu só precisava adicionar `entityManager.joinTransaction();` nos meus métodos: salvar, atualizar e excluir ... então isso é tudo :) Agora posso acessar várias bases de dados de forma dinâmica e não é lento.